# Why spin-orbit coupling in TMDCs is strong?

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, orbitals

I already know about spin-orbit coupling in QM.
Spin-orbit coulping is that spin of electron and it`s orbital(angular momentum) are considered for getting Hamiltonian which can cause energy splitting.
Based on this concept, I have troubled with understanding strong spin-orbit coupling in TMDCs.

Is there anyone who can let me know why spin-orbit coupling in TMDCs is strong?

Comment: What is TMDC? The only situation with strong spin-orbit splitting that I am aware of is nuclear physics.

Comment: @LewisMiller TMDC is a transition metal dichalcogenides which is important in valleytronics and spintronics.

Comment: Thanks.  I have no idea why spin-orbit coupling would be strong in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

Spin-orbit splittings increase with atomic number because it is a relativistic effect. So it is higher for Te and Se than for sulphides and oxides.

Comment: for hydrogenic atoms it scales as $Z^4$ (since Bohr radius decreases as $1/Z$ and SO depends on $\langle 1/r^4 \rangle$

Comment: +1 this is the right answer. For the record, spin orbit coupling in these materials isn't even that strong,  it's just much stronger than graphene or silicon.

Comment: @IamAStudent Yes. But the relevant orbitals here are the valence orbitals, and those have approximately the same size for oxygen, sulfur, selenium and tellurium.

Comment: really? I thought they would differ because of different principal quantum numbers. Anyway, focusing on length scale may be a little misleading since SO really comes from $B = v \times E$ and for hydrogenic atom it's written as $L/(mr^2) \times e/r^2$ but I guess the r-scaling could be different in a more complex situation

Comment: and also, my comments about scalingare actually wrong...the r-scaling is $1/r^3$, not $1/r^4$ since $v \sim L/mr$. So you get your $Z^3$ from there and the last factor of $Z$ from the strength of the electric field $Ze/r^2$